# How can i send my object to server once the connection is established

Tags: android

I have created the connection to server using "Https" protocol. Here is my code...

```
String httpsURL = "https://abc.com/auth/login/";
HttpsURLConnection con = null; 
try{
URL url = new URL(httpsURL);
con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST" );
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.connect();
String respMessage = con.getResponseMessage();
int respCode = con.getResponseCode();
}catch(....){....}
```

Now i have to send my object to server over that connection. How can i do that??? And, what is the best format of object to send it to server?? Can i send my HashMap object? Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert...

```
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
```

...into your code and start writing.  What you can send depends on what your server is expecting.

Comment: sorry. i didn't get you. could you elaborate your answer? please. My app data is in the form of HashMap object. How can i write that object to OutputStream?

Comment: I hate to sound flippant, but you can write it any way you like.  It all depends on what the server is expecting and you haven't said anything about what's on the other side of the conversation or whether you are even in control of it.

Comment: My server is expecting the object which consists of Name-Value pairs. So, i used HashMap.

Comment: *sigh* I'm talking about a specification, contract, or protocol... How is the server expecting you to deliver the name/value pairs?  Are you in control of the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the object implement the interface Serializable.

why not try JSON